# Increment MATLAB range

Tags: matlab, indexing, range, increment

I'm not sure of an easier way to increment a range of numbers to use as an index to extract specific ranges in a series of numbers in a 12-number sequence.  For example, I need an index to do the following:

`Array1` is an array of 1 row by 612 columns.  I need to create an index so that I"m extracting values 8,9,10,11 and 12 and then incrementing those by 12 so that the next columns I extract are 20, 21, 22, 23 and 24 and so forth to c`olumn == 612`.

My index will look like this:

```
index = [ 8 9 10 11 12 20 21 22 23 24 32 33 34 35 36 ]
```

etc to 612.

I tried using something like `index = [ 8:12:12:612]` but it just gives me `[ 8 20 32, etc]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

```
S = 12;  %// major step (minor step is 1)
G = 5;   %// group size
I = 8;   %// initial value
F = 612; %// ending value
```

Then the indices can be generated with this simple [`mod`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mod.html)-based approach:

```
index = find(mod(0:F-1,S)<G)+I-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`bsxfun` based approach -

```
array1 = 8:12; %// Starting array
sz = 12; %// Stepsize

Ncols = floor((size(A,2)-array1(1))/sz)+1 %// No. of blocks of indices
ind1 = bsxfun(@plus,array1.',[0:Ncols-1]*sz) %//' Indices in blocks
index = ind1(ind1<=size(A,2)); %// Valid indices
```

---

Example -

```
A = rand(1,23); %// Random input for demo
array1 = 1:4; %// Starting array
sz = 8; %// Stepsize
```

Output -

```
index =
     1     2     3     4     9    10    11    12    17    18    19    20
```